# Is there an ARM decompiler that is inexpensive, mature, and produces high-quality results?

Tags: assembly, arm, decompiling, decompiler

I am looking for a decompiler (convert binary/asm to C/pseudo code).

I know about IDAPro decompiler, but it's really expensive.

Also, I know about [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/), but it's ARM decompiler isn't ready yet for prime time.

Have you seen anything else out there?

**Update**

[Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/index.php) - doesn't support ARM

[vm64dec](https://code.google.com/p/vm64dec/downloads/list)- doesn't support ARM

P.S. I am familiar with Google :) However, most of Google results are x86 decompilers (rather ARM). Also, Google can't tell whether decompilation results are decent or not.

Comment: I see a few [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=arm+decompiler+open+source).

Comment: Just as a comment - decompilers tend to produce unreadable code for humans. Unless it is a large project, it may be worth reverse engineering the software (using, instead, a disassembler) and recreating the source code yourself (assuming you're proficient in ARM assembly and C).

Comment: @RageD: I am aware that decompilers doesn't always produce good code. However, I would rather run decompiler and see approximation of the code than go through 40 pages of ASM code with paper and pencil tracking which register contains what.

Comment: @VictorRonin: Please see my update to the title of your question.  If you're going to ask a question that's [clearly off-topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), it needs to be Academy-award quality.

Comment: @RageD: you're wrong, see [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/compare.shtml) (disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays).

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: Fair point. Those are some pretty compelling samples; even more so when you consider the amount of work it actually takes to do this by hand. Thanks for this!

Comment: [capstone/cstool](https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone)